# How do I combine multiple select statements to echo results in a table row using php?

Tags: php, postgresql

I am trying to combine three select statements from the same table in order to use the results to complete a . The code am currently using returns:

Resource id #3  Resource id #4  Resource id #5

I have done some research on UNION or JOIN, but I haven't found anything that works. Here is my current approach:

```
$statecount = pg_query($conn, "
SELECT 
  COUNT (*) as totalst
FROM 
  fpscdb001_ws_001.incident
WHERE
  incident.initial_symptom = 'Chrome Install' AND
  incident.state_1 = 'MA';");

$sched = pg_query($conn, "
SELECT
  COUNT (*) as totalsch
FROM
  fpscdb001_ws_001.incident
WHERE
  incident.initial_symptom = 'Chrome Install' AND
  incident.state_1 = 'MA' AND
  incident.status_1 = 'Scheduled';");

$closed = pg_query($conn, "
 SELECT
  COUNT (*) as totaldone
FROM
  fpscdb001_ws_001.incident
WHERE
  incident.initial_symptom = 'Chrome Install' AND
  incident.state_1 = 'MA' AND
  incident.status_1 = 'Closed';");

  if (!$statecount) {
          echo "Query failed on state count.\n";
          exit;
        }
  if (!$sched) {
          echo "Query failed on sched.\n";
          exit;
        }
  if (!$closed) {
          echo "Query failed on closed.\n";
          exit;
        }
        {
          echo "<td> $statecount </td>";
          echo "<td> $sched </td>";
          echo "<td> $closed </td>";
        }
pg_close($conn);
```

Comment: You can defiantly use `UNION` on these, show the `UNION` you attempted so we can help you fix it.

Comment: I have yet to find an explanation of how to notate UNION in the statements that I can understand. At least not while declaring different variables.

Answer (score 0):

Through some trial and error I was able to make it work...

```
$statecount = pg_query($conn, "
SELECT 
  COUNT (*) as totalst
FROM 
  fpscdb001_ws_001.incident
WHERE
  incident.initial_symptom = 'Chrome Upgrade' AND
  incident.state_1 = 'AR' AND
  incident.status_1 != 'Closed'

UNION ALL

SELECT
  COUNT (*) as totalsch
FROM
  fpscdb001_ws_001.incident
WHERE
  incident.initial_symptom = 'Chrome Upgrade' AND
  incident.state_1 = 'AR' AND
  incident.staging = 'True' AND
  incident.is_installed != 'True' AND
  incident.status_1 != 'Closed'

UNION ALL

SELECT
  COUNT (*) as totaldone
FROM
  fpscdb001_ws_001.incident
WHERE
  incident.initial_symptom = 'Chrome Upgrade' AND
  incident.state_1 = 'AR' AND
  incident.staging = 'True' AND
  incident.is_installed = 'True';");

  if (!$statecount) {
          echo "Query failed on state count.\n";
          exit;
        }

        while ($counts = pg_fetch_row($statecount)){
          echo "<td>$counts[0]</td>";
        }
```